# List all app users?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to know if there is a way to list all users who installed my app through api calls ? 
I need a list of users ID to automatically update their status using my facebook application

Thanks in advance

Comment: if this answered your question, check it off so that it closes

Answer (score 1):

if your app requires a one time login, do it then. otherwise have a script that only runs on initial app start